# How do I loop the part of the code that I specified above?

Tags: python-unittest

In the `word_verification()` function, if the condition "'There is no such word in the dictionary.'", then the request for the introduction of the word should appear again. How can I loop????
Please help me!)

One library commissioned you to write a program for digitizing synonyms dictionaries. N pairs of words are submitted to enter the program. Each word is a synonym for its paired word.

Implement code that compiles a dictionary of synonyms (all words in the dictionary are different), then asks the user for a word and displays its synonym on the screen. Provide input control: if there is no such word, output an error and request the word again. In this case, the check should not depend on the case of characters.

```
name_of_numbers = {1: 'Первая', 2: 'Вторая', 3: 'Третья', 4: 'Четвертая', 5: 'Пятая', 6: 'Шестая', 7: 'Седьмая', 8: 'Восьмая', 9: 'Девятая', 10: 'Десятая', 11: 'Одиннадцатая', 12: 'Двенадцатая', 13: 'Тринадцатая', 14: 'Четырнадцатая', 15: 'Пятнадцатая', 16: 'Шестнадцатая', 17: 'Семнадцатая', 18: 'Восемнадцатая', 19: 'Девятнадцатая'}

the_word_couple = 'пара'

tenths = {2: 'двадцать', 3: 'тридцать', 4: 'сорок', 5: 'пятьдесят', 6: 'шестьдесят', 7: 'семьдесят', 8: 'восемьдесят', 9: 'девяносто'}

round_numbers = {20: 'двадцатая', 30: 'тридцатая', 40: 'сороковая', 50: 'пятидесятая', 60: 'шестидесятая', 70: 'семидесятая', 80: 'восьмидесятая', 90: 'девяностая'}


def get_numbers_by_text():
    pairs_list = []
    number_of_pairs = int(input('Введите количество пар слов: '))

    for number in range(1, number_of_pairs + 1):
        if number <= 19:
            write_pairs = input(f'{name_of_numbers[number]} '
                                f'{the_word_couple}: ').split()
            write_pairs.remove('—')
        elif str(number)[1] != '0':
            write_pairs = input(f'{tenths[int(str(number)[0])].title()} '
                                f'{name_of_numbers[int(str(number)[1])].lower()} '
                                f'{the_word_couple}: ').split()
            write_pairs.remove('—')
        else:
            write_pairs = input(f'{round_numbers[number].title()} '
                                f'{the_word_couple}: ').split()
            write_pairs.remove('—')
        pairs_list.append(write_pairs)

    return pairs_list


def creating_a_dictionary():
    using_the_list = get_numbers_by_text()
    pairs_dict = {i_pair[0]: i_pair[1] for i_pair in using_the_list}

    return pairs_dict


# def search_for_synonyms():
#     while True:
#         word = input('Введите слово: ')
#         return word


def word_verification():
    using_the_dictionary = creating_a_dictionary()
    # using_word = search_for_synonyms()
    # word = input('Введите слово: ')
    while True:
        word = input('Введите слово: ')
        for letter_key, letter_value in using_the_dictionary.items():
            if letter_key == word:
                result = f'Синоним {letter_value}'
            elif letter_value == word:
                result = f'Синоним {letter_key}'
            else:
                result = 'Такого слова в словаре нет.'
            return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    word_verification()
```